# How to move a list of turtles from right to left on the screen without stopping inside a while loop?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm developing the Space Invaders game and I want to create a list of turtles as enemies, in a separate class. I want to move this list from right to left, to the edge of the screen, until the end of the game (while loop). How do to ?

main.py:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from enemy import Enemy

def space_invaders():
    # SCREEN :
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(width=800, height=800)
    screen.title("Space Invaders")
    screen.bgcolor("gray1")
    screen.tracer(0)

    # INSTANCE OF CLASSES :
    enemy = Enemy()

    # CREATES & DISPLAY ENEMIES :
    enemy.create_enemies()

    # WHILE THE GAME IS PLAYING :
    play_game = True
    while play_game:
        screen.update()
        # enemy.move_enemies_left()
        sleep(0.05)
        # enemy.move_enemies_right()
        sleep(0.05)

space_invaders()
```

enemy.py:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Enemy(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nb_enemy = 10
        self.enemies = []

    def create_enemies(self):
        x = 0
        for nb in range(self.nb_enemy):
            enemy = Turtle()
            enemy.shapesize(1.2)
            enemy.shape("triangle")
            enemy.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=1)
            enemy.color("red")
            enemy.right(90)
            enemy.penup()
            enemy.goto(x=-225 + x, y=345)
            enemy.color("purple")
            self.enemies.append(enemy)
            x += 50

    def move_enemies_left(self):
        x = 2
        for nb in range(5):
            for enemy in self.enemies:
                enemy.goto(x=enemy.xcor() - x, y=enemy.ycor())

    def move_enemies_right(self):
        x = 2
        for nb in range(5):
            for enemy in self.enemies:
                    enemy.goto(x=enemy.xcor() + x, y=enemy.ycor())

    def refresh_enemies(self):
        self.nb_enemy -= 1
```

I want to keep the classes separate from the main.py and be able to trigger the functions of the enemy class from the while loop. Is this the right thing to do or do I have to create the enemy movement function from main.py ?

Comment: This works fine and using methods like you have done and calling them is definitely better. Instead of a while loop, an event-driven approach with use of mainloop() will be better. Maybe you can include a timer within the enemy class and then whenever the timer is started with an enemy.start_move() method, the enemy object could start moving.